# How to print stuff on the same row

Tags: python, function, loops, printing

im writing a pyhton program that basically calculates the probability of the sum of a two dices. I'm using a print function to make a table, but apparently i can't print multiple stuff on the same row.

to get the sum of the dices i used the random libary, it looks like this:

```
question = int(input("How many times do you want to roll the dices: "))

def sum():
    for x in range(question):
       dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
       dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
       sum = dice1 + dice2
       print(sum)

def attempts():
      for attempts in rang(question):
             print(attempts)
```

Output:....

```
attempts        sum of the dices         probability
-----------------------------------------------------
    1
    2
    3 
                           4
                           9
                           3
                                                      100%
```

- how do i make everything print in one column?
  thanks in advance for your help :/

Comment: Don't use multiple loops. Put all the dice results in a list. Then loop over the list, printing all the information about that roll in the same row.

Comment: Your question is about print formatting, the fact that the values happen to be random is irrelevant. I've removed the `random` tag since your question is not about "random numbers and their generators, whether pseudo-random or truly random".

Answer (score 0):

Separate your logic. Don't have the function that's calculating the value also be responsible for printing it to the screen -- make your main function do that. Then it can format it appropriately.

```py
def dice_rolls(roll_count):
    # return a list of length `roll_count` which is two dice rolls
    return [random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1, 6) for _ in roll_count]

def main():
    num_rolls = int(input("How many rolls? "))
    rolls = dice_rolls(num_rolls)
    attempts = range(1, num_rolls+1)
    # loop over each row
    for attempt, roll in zip(attempts, rolls):
        print(f"{attempt}\t{roll}")  # or however you want to format it

main()
```